# Is it possible to use a scope as source for association with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, simple-form

Is it possible to use a scope as source for association?

```
class User < AR
  scope :active_users, where('status = 4')
  ...

# form
<%= f.association :active_users %>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think that will work. A scope returns an ActiveRecord::Relation and simple_form is looking for a symbol that represents an existing ActiveRecord::Association (E.g. has_many, belongs_to).

Comment: Surely there must be a way. Or do you have to just create the form field manually without simple_form?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

You can use collection for source

in controller

```
@active_users = User.active_users
```

in view

```
<%= f.association :active_user, collection: @active_users %>
```

Comment: How does this solve the original poster's problem? Add some explanation, please.