# Simple_form f.association on subset of Model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rolify

I've got a model, Agency, which `has_many :users`.  Users can have roles- :agent, :admin, so I created methods to pull that subset of @agency.users

```
Agency.rb
def agents
  users.with_roles(:agent, self)
end
```

What I want is, effectively, `f.association :agents, collection: User.all` to allow agencies to hire anybody.  Trying this gives, unsurprisingly, "Association :agents not found".  Changing it to `f.association @agency.agents, collection: User.all` also fails with `"Association #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation .....not found"`

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613859/is-it-possible-to-use-a-scope-as-source-for-association-with-simple-form), it seems like simpleform can't handle the AssociationRelation, but only an Association.

Can I alter my method to return just an association?  Can I alter my simpleform to handle the AssociationRelation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution turned out to be a bit hacky, but it seems to work:

I *do* need it to be an association, rather than methods, but it turned out I could scope my associations.

```
Agency.rb
has_many :bridge_roles, -> {where(resource_type: 'Agency')}, class_name: 'Role', foreign_key: :resource_id
has_many :agents, -> {where('roles.name=?', 'agent')}, class_name: 'User', through: :bridge_roles, source: :users
```

The key being that I created the bridge explicitly to make the association aware of the rolify roles.  Through that, I can access the set of Users I care about.